# Xpath to locate an element using a text outside of the tag

Tags: xpath

how can I select the input element using "ABQ". Below xpath is not working.

```
//div[contains(text(),'Pick-up')]/following::label/input[contains(text(),'ABQ')]
```

Sample input (edited for OP)

```
<div class="col-xs-2 profile-location-panal profile-pickupLocationPanel">
    <!--Locations-->
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-class="{'panel-invalid':isSaveProfileClicked&amp;&amp;profileInformationForm.locations.$error.required}">
        <div class="panel-heading">Pick-up Locations</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panalScroll">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAllLocations()" ng-checked="checkLocationsAll()">All
                    </label>
                </div>
                <!-- ngRepeat: item in pickUpLocations --><div class="checkbox ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in pickUpLocations">
                    <label class="ng-binding">
                        <input name="locations" required="required" type="checkbox" ng-required="selected.pickUpLocations.length==0" checklist-value="item.code" checklist-model="selected.pickUpLocations">
                        ABQ
                    </label>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3K9H.jpg

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML input?

Comment: <label class="ng-binding">
 <input name="locations" checklist-model="selected.pickUpLocations">
 ABQ
</label>

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML doesn't look like valid XML (note that the closing tag for `<input>` is missing), so XPath won't work.

Comment: The code is written in angularjs and this is what i am getting while inspect element on chrome.

Comment: Anyways i did rnd on my own and now able to do it by 

//div[contains(text(),'Pick-up')]/following::div/label[contains(.,'ABQ')]

Comment: @user2930871 HTML doesn't have to be valid XML to work. XPath, on the other hand, may fail if the document is not well-formed.